# Perform any functions passed through the data tag

Tags: jquery

I intend on passing through some callback functions I need to tap into through a data tag.

```
<div data-callback-functions="function01(),function02(),function03()"></div>
```

How can I grab these functions passed through and perform them in order? I assume I'm allowed to use brackets for the functions within the data-tag?

Comment: Why was this down rated? It's a perfectly valid question???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"I assume I'm allowed to use brackets for the functions within the data-tag?"*

Yes, that is valid markup.

> *"How can I grab these functions passed through and perform them in order?"*

Assuming you already have a reference to the div in `this` (adapt as needed):

```
var funcs = $(this).data("callback-functions");
eval(funcs);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qPfzZ/

The [`eval()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) executes an arbitrary string of JS. Your `data-` attribute contains valid JS.

Comment: Cool so the eval will execute the functions? Do I need to worry about stripping out the commas between the functions?

Comment: You don't have to strip the commas because your `data-` attribute contains valid JS _with_ the commas.

Comment: You are awesome dude big thanks! I was worried I was going to have to use an array and all sorts. Many thanks again! :)